# Inbound & outbound emails marked as phishing

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, phishing

We look after multiple Office 365 tenants for hosted Exchange email.

One tenant in particular has an issue where a lot of inbound and outbound emails are marked as phishing.

[image: This message was identified as a phishing scam]

The domain passes all DNS checks under the Admin console, and I can't find the domain on any blacklist checks.

SPF: v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

I investigated enabling DKIM, however unfortunately the domain registrar does not accept underscores in CNAME records.

Can someone please help? The issue is very frustrating for our client.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use CNAMES to setup the sub-domain for DKIM.  Same applies to DMARC.

Comment: @BillThor why not... I would suggest the exact opposite, always use cnames for 3rd party dkim.

Comment: @ash get a new DNS provider or registrar, which you could easily switch to Google DNS (highly recommend) or cloudflare (also recommend) both support dnssec.

Comment: I found out the issue was due to web links within users' signatures. This domain/website is marked as phishing for some reason. Thanks for your help.